# How can I get the value of the next Node? It always return the last Node

Tags: c++, pointers, getter-setter

```cpp
class Node{
    private:
        int value;
        Node *next;
    public:
        Node(int aValue){
            value = aValue;
            cout<< "Node created: " << value <<endl;
        }
        void setValue(int newValue){
            value = newValue;
        }
        int getValue(){
            return value;
        }
        void setNext(Node node){
            next = &node;
        }
        Node nextNode(){
            return *next;
        }
};

int main (){
    Node nodeA(29);
    Node nodeB(3);
    Node nodeC(56);
    Node nodeD(72);
    Node nodeE(69);

    nodeA.setNext(nodeB);
    nodeB.setNext(nodeC);
    nodeC.setNext(nodeD);
    nodeD.setNext(nodeE);

    cout<< nodeA.nextNode().getValue();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please put text into the body of your question.  Describe your problem in detail including expected and actual results, and things you have tried.  See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `setNext` gets argument *by copy*. You take the address of that copy and store it, but the copy dies immediately after function finished. You are not allowed to dereference that address after the function end, because the object is invalid.

Comment: setNext has UB, youre taking the address of a temporary node because you pass it by copy to the function

Comment: Looks like you have more to learn about pointers.  Make this change: `void setNext(Node *node) { next = node; }`

Comment: that's what I did in my earlier version of my code, but I got errors so I rewrite it and came up with this new one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EricEchemane It's one of the issues with being a beginner. Everyone gets errors but beginners often don't understand the cause of the error. In that situation changes to your code are as likely to make things worse as make things better.

Comment: Wow! such a very meaningful message for us-beginners. That's a very nice line!. Thanks you Sir.

Answer (score 4):

Linked list methods should use *pointers*. Look at your version of `setNext`

```
    void setNext(Node node){
        next = &node;
    }
```

As you can see this stores the address of the node parameter, that's not the same as the address of the node object in main. And because the node parameter no longer exists once the `setNext` method exits you end up storing an invalid address.

Try this instead

```
    void setNext(Node* node){
        next = node;
    }
    Node* nextNode(){
        return next;
    }

int main()
{
    ...
    nodeA.setNext(&nodeB);
    nodeB.setNext(&nodeC);
    nodeC.setNext(&nodeD);
    nodeD.setNext(&nodeE);

    cout<< nodeA.nextNode()->getValue(); 
}
```

Comment: should use pointers? Those two would be fine with references as well, no?

Comment: Well I assume that eventually some dynamic allocation will be involved and pointers would be preferable then.

Comment: i dont have a cs degree, so I never had to write my own linked lists (It was a serious question). Maybe I should look at some list exercises one day

Comment: @idclev463035818 A reasonable linked list implementation should use pointers, because it should be the owner of the nodes. OP's version would be fine with references, but I can't imagine a list being usable when implemented like this (because it moves the node ownership and lifetime control to the user, which defeats the whole point of using data structure).

Comment: @idclev463035818 Linked lists are one of the things every programmer should understand.

Comment: @user253751 every programmer should know how to make good coffee, the rest follows as corollaries

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior.

```
    void setNext(Node node){
        next = &node;
    }
```

You store the address of the local `node`. Once this function returns `node` no longer exists and `next` is a dangling pointer. Dereferencing that invalid pointer later in `nextNode` invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

where are you updating the value after setting the "next"??

what about doing

```
void setNext(Node* node){
    next = node;
    value = node->value;
}


int getValue(){
    return next->value;
}
```

Comment: I just create that method for future purposes only and that has nothing to do with my problem. HEHE thanks by the way.